# Is it possible to have 2 Models loaded for one entity kind to support data migration?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, data-migration

I am writing a datastore migration for our current production App Engine application.

We made some fairly extensive changes to the data model so I am trying to put in place an architecture to allow easier migrations in the future.  This includes test suites for the migrations and common class structures for migration scripts.

I am running into a problem with my current strategy. For both the migrations and the test scripts I need a way to load the Model classes from the old schema and the Model classes for the new data schema into memory at the same time and load entities using either.

Here is an example set of schemas.

rev1.py

```
class Account(db.Model):
  _version      = db.IntegerProperty(default = 1)
  user          = db.UserProperty(auto_current_user_add = True, required = True)
  name          = db.StringProperty()
  contact_email = db.EmailProperty()
```

rev2.py

```
class Account(db.Model):
  _version = db.IntegerProperty(default = 2)
  auth_id  = db.StringProperty()
  name     = db.StringProperty()
  pwd_hash = db.StringProperty(required = True, indexed = False)
```

A migration script may look something like:

```
import rev1
import rev2

class MyMigration(...):
   def isNeeded(self):
      num_accounts = num_entities_with_version(rev1.Account, 1)
      return num_accounts > 0

   def run(self):
       rev1_accounts = rev1.Account.all()
       for account in [a for a in rev1_accounts if account._version == 1]:
           auth_id = account.contact_email
           if auth_id is None or auth_id == '':
              auth_id = account.user.email()

              new_account = rev2.Account.create(auth_id = auth_id,
                                                name    = account.name)
```

And a test suite would look something like this:

```
import rev1
import rev2

class MyTest(...):
   def testIt(self):
      # Setup data
      act1 = rev1.Account(name = '..', contact_email = '..')
      act1.put()
      act2 = rev1.Account(name = '..', contact_email = '..')
      act2.put()

      # Run migration
      migration.run()

      # Check results
      accounts = rev2.Account.all().fetch(99)
```

So as you can see I am using the old revision in two ways.  I am using it in the migration as a way to read data in the old format and convert it into the new format.  (note: I can't read it in the new format because of things like the required pwd_hash field and other field changes).  I am using it in the test suite to setup test data in the old format before running the migration.

It all seems great in theory, but in practice it falls apart because GAE doesn't allow multiple models to be loaded for the same kind, or more specifically, queries only return for the most recently defined model.

In the development server this seems to be due to the fact that the process of calling get() on a query for an entity (ex: Account.get(my_key)) calls a result hook that builds the result Model object by calling class_for_kind on the entity kind name from the data.  So even though I may call rev2.Account.get(), it may build up rev1.Account Model objects because the kind 'Account' maps to rev1.Account in the _kind_map dictionary.

This has made me rethink my migration strategy a bit and I wanted to ask if anyone has thoughts.  Specifically:

1. Would it be safe to manually override google.appengine.ext.db._kind_map at runtime in test and on the production servers to allow this migration method to work?
2. Is there some better way to keep two versions of a Model in memory at the same time?
3. Is there a different migration method that may be a smarter way to go about this work?

Other methods I have thought of trying include:

- Change the entity kind when the version changes.  (use kind() to change it)  Then when we migrate we move all classes to the new kind name.
- Find a way to query the entities and get back a 'raw' object (proto buffers??) that has not been built into a full object.  (would not work with tests)
- 'Just Do It Live': Don't write tests for any of this and just try to migrate using the latest schema loading the older data working around issues as the come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are actually several questions within the greater question.  There seem to be two key questions here though, one is how to test and the other is how to really do it.

I wouldn't define the kind multiple times; as you've noted there are nuances to doing this, and, if you wind up with the wrong model loaded, you'll get all sorts of headaches.  That said, it is completely possible for you to manipulate the kind_map.  I've done this in some special cases, but I try to avoid it when possible.

For a live migration where you've got significant schema changes, you've got two choices: use [Expando](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/expandoclass.html) or use the [lower level API](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py#1462).  When adding required fields, you might find it easier to use Expando, then run a migration to add the new information, then switch back to a plain db.Model.  The lower-level API sits right under the ext.db stuff, and it presents the entity as a Python dict.  This can be very convenient for manipulating an entity.  Use whichever method you're more comfortable with.  I prefer Expando when posible, since it is a higher level interface, but it is a two-step process.

For testing, I'd personally suggest you focus on the actual conversion routines.  So instead of testing the method from the point of querying down, test to ensure your conversion routines themselves function correctly.  You might even choose to pass in the old entity as a Python dict, then return the new entity.

I'd make one other adjustment here as well.  I'd rather use a query to find all my rev 1 accounts.  That's the great thing about having an indexed _version on your models.  You can trivially find things that need migrated.

Also, check out Google's [article on updating schemas](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema.html).  It is old, but still good.

Comment: Any thoughts on the idea of creating a new kind for the case when there is a significant schema change.  It seems like this would allow something similar to using Expando but allow the migration to happen in one pass.  (ie. load all the old entities for the rev1.Account (kind:acct_v1) then save them out to the new model rev2.Account (kind:acct_v2) ).  This seems a bit cleaner to me then temporarily introducing Expando and then pulling it back out.  It may have the added benefit of allowing testing the full process.  No doubt I am missing something though.

Comment: I gotta say I like the idea of changing the kind to indicate the version. That can be pretty clean. If this is too big a gun I'd go the temporary Expando route. You could also temporarily drop the 'required' flags from the new fields, then you can change the entities in-place and you still have some type-safety. But notice that you can't completely get rid of old properties this way -- that requires temporarily using Expando. However you could do that clean-up step in a one-off map/reduce job that runs off-line after you've converted all your entities to the new schema. Don't mess w. kind map.

Comment: I'd think updating the kind to indicate the version is probably good in two cases: 1) really major schema changes and 2) when you don't have a lot of references to that model (or they are all by key name/id).  If you've got a lot of cross-references you may just be making a big mess.

Comment: @GuidovanRossum I agree that changing the kind could be clean. Glad to see I am not the only one.  I will be looking into this and the expando method.

Comment: @RobertKluin Agreed on the cross references.  Reconnecting everything could be a complete pain since all my cross references are by key.  I would have to go change every place they have changed.  I think some type of hybrid solution may be my best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to simply do the migration on version 2, leaving the old attributes on the model and setting them to None after you update the version.  This will clear out the space they use but will still leave them defined.  Then in a following release you can just remove them from the model.

This method is pretty simple, but does require two releases to remove old attribute completely, so is more akin to deprecating the existing attributes.

Comment: Doesn't this fail when adding required fields?  At least it seems to in my testcase with the new password_hash field.  I could probably make it so the first time the attribute is introduced it is not required and then make it required in the following version once everything is migrated but I was trying to avoid a multi-pass conversion process.

Comment: I'd say don't make that field required right away.  Check it in your business logic (for now at least).